# Hyper-V Migration Windows 10

Tags: centos, virtual-machines, hyper-v, windows-10

I'm trying to import an exported VM from a Microsoft Hyper-V instance running on a Windows 10 node to another Windows 10 node.
As far as I know the 2 hosts are exactly the same in terms of hardware.
So I performed the export and placed the generated folders onto a USB stick.
On the destination host, it doesn't find anything when attempting the import , its fine if i try the import on the source host.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you check the file permissions?

Comment: Did you check that both hosts have same config version?